# Setting the scroll location without setting a default time

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using the latest timepicker.co control with the following parameters:

```
        $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
            interval: 15,
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true
        });
```

I want to allow any time, but I don't want to set a default.  I find it annoying that the display starts at 12:00 AM a d I have to scroll all the way down to more useful times.  I don't like the way startTime works, changing the order of things in the list (putting earlier times at the bottom).  That just seems confusing.

What I want to do is set it up so that the list starts with a specified time already scrolled into view, BUT NOT SELECTED.  Is this possible?

ANSWER:

```
$('input.timepicker').click(function(){
    if(document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox.ClientID%>').value == null ||
        document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox.ClientID%>').value.length == 0) {
        $('.ui-timepicker-viewport').scrollTop(765);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll the content on input click for example to achieve what you want.

for example

```
$('input.timepicker').click(function(){
    $('.ui-timepicker-viewport').scrollTop(1000);
})
```

The above snippet will make the times start at 8:00AM

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxx1nw3q/3/)

Comment: This worked great.  I had to adjust the number a bit for my time resolution.  I added a bit of detection so that it only executed when there wasn't a selection.  If an entry is selected, the selection is scrolled into view.